# laravel 9 cron job task scheduling. Call script

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I came across a situation I want to call from laravel 9 project dayly php

script from another domen.

```
I have a script for example at **support.com/my_script.php**

And I have a project on laravel 9 support.pro.com

At **support.com** I run dayly script **my_script.php** and I use cron job. 

Is it possible to run dayly **support.com/my_script.php** from laravel 9
```

(support.pro.com) project using Task Scheduling with Cron job in Laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a command which trigger the method.
2. Trigger the command by `crontab` daily.
3. Add the line at the bottom of crontab.

- Linux: `sudo crontab -e`
- `* * * * php /var/www/html/<project_directory>/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`